# Spring mvc validation using tabbed form to show

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am a beginner with Spring MVC. I have developed a simple Signup and Login application.

I styled Signup and Login page to be on same page(tabbed) using bootstrap and CSS letting the Login (tab) to be active. The code works fine if any validation error occurs, but my problem is that when a validation error occurs it returns to the view where Login tab is active, when I click the Signup tab, there it show the error messages next to fields.

I want the Signup page to be active so that the user can see error message at first go. Also I want to prevent a new form from loading every time after validation.

Please help to solve this.
Thank you.
Following is my code.

index2.jsp

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-login">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <a href="#" id="signup-form-link">Signup</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form"
                                style="display: block;">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password"
                                        tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group text-center">
                                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember"
                                        id="remember"> <label for="remember">
                                        Remember Me</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                                                tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login"
                                                value="Log In">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="text-center">
                                                <a href="https://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5"
                                                    class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>


                            <form:form id="signup-form" action="validateSignUp" role="form"
                                style="display: none;" commandName="signUpObj" >

                                <div class="form-group">

                                        <form:input path="userName" tabindex="1"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value=""/>
                                        <form:errors path="userName"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                        <form:input path="email" tabindex="1"
                                        class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value=""/>
                                        <form:errors path="email"/>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">


                                        <form:password path="password" 
                                        tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/>
                                        <form:errors path="password"/>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                            <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit"
                                                tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-signup"
                                                value="Signup Now">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <%--                                </form> --%>
                            </form:form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

SignUpController.java

```
package com.controllers;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.entities.SignUp;
import com.services.SignUpService;

@Controller
public class SignUpController {

    @Autowired
    SignUpService signUpService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/showSignUp",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showSignUpPage(Map<String, Object> model) {
         SignUp signUpObj=new SignUp();
         model.put("signUpObj", signUpObj);
        return "SignUp";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/index",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showIndex(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("in conto");

         SignUp signUpObj=new SignUp();

         model.put("signUpObj", signUpObj);
        return "index2";
    }





}
```

ValidationController.java

```
package com.controllers;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.entities.SignUp;
import com.services.SignUpService;
import com.validators.SignUpValidator;

@Controller
public class ValidationController {

    @Autowired
    SignUpService signUpService;

    @Autowired
    SignUpValidator signUpValidator;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/validateSignUp")
    public String validateSignUp(@Valid @ModelAttribute("signUpObj") SignUp signUpObj, BindingResult result,
            Map<String, Object> model) {


        signUpValidator.validate(signUpObj, result);
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return "index2";
        }
        else
        {
            signUpService.newSignUp(signUpObj);
            System.out.println(signUpObj.getSignId()+"---"+signUpObj.getUserName());
            model.put("signUpObj", signUpObj);
            return "AddUser";
        }

    }

}
```

SignUpValidator.java

```
package com.validators;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.entities.SignUp;
import com.services.SignUpService;

@Component
public class SignUpValidator implements Validator {
    @Autowired
    SignUpService signUpService;

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        SignUp obj = (SignUp) target;

        // for SignUp verification
        if (!obj.getUserName().isEmpty()) {
            SignUp verifyObj = signUpService.getSignUp(obj);
            if (verifyObj != null)
                errors.rejectValue("userName", "error.userName", "User Name already exists");

        }
        if (obj.getUserName().equals("") || obj.getUserName().isEmpty()) {

            errors.rejectValue("userName", "error.userName", "User Name mandatory");
        }

        else if (obj.getPassword().isEmpty()) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "error.password", "Password is mandatory");
        } else if (obj.getPassword().length() < 3 || obj.getPassword().length() > 6) {
            errors.rejectValue("password", "errors.password", "Password must be  3 to 6 characters");
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following javascript to your `index2.jsp` just before ending `<body>` tag

```
<script>
   <spring:hasBindErrors name="signUpObj">
        $("#signup-form-link").trigger("click");
    </spring:hasBindErrors>
</script>
```

Add `spring` tag lib to your jsp if not used.

`<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>`

Comment: Hello @Zico, thanks for the suggestion, <spring:hasBindErros> helped in catching the error, but $("#signup-form-link").trigger("click"); did not work, so I used the same code used to display the signup tab details inside <sprin:hasBindErrors> tag, that worked, thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are rendering your view without clean your wrong values, try it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validateSignUp")
    public ModelAndView validateSignUp(@Valid @ModelAttribute("signUpObj") SignUp signUpObj, BindingResult result,
            Map<String, Object> model) {


        signUpValidator.validate(signUpObj, result);
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            return new ModelAndView("index2", "singUpObj", new SingUp());
        }
        else
        {
            signUpService.newSignUp(signUpObj);
            System.out.println(signUpObj.getSignId()+"---"+signUpObj.getUserName());
            return new ModelAndView("AddUser", "singUpObj", signUpObj);
        }

    }
```

[EDIT]

Here an ajax call example:

```
$('#login-form').on('submit', function(event){

        var self = this;
        var form = $(this);
        var errorMsg = $('#errorMsg');


        if (form.data('requestRunning')) {
            return;
        }

        form.data('requestRunning', true);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr("action"),
            type: form.attr("method"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result){

               console.log(result.login);
               if(result.login == undefined){
                   self.submit();
               }else{
                   errorMsg.text(result.login.FAILURE).addClass("alert alert-danger");

               }

            },
            complete: function (e) {               
                form.data('requestRunning', false);
           }

        });
```

regards,

Comment: Hello @Ivan Lynch, the previous code is working fine.I tried your code,it just erases the error details and send back to the login page. Is there a way for not loading the page again i.e. when I press back button , previous information is displayed.

Comment: That is because browsers implement something known as back-forward cache when you hit back/forward to make your browser faster, i think is good idea create an ajax call if you don't want to refresh your browser in every call to your controller

Comment: i'll add an example of ajax call